# System "UI has Stopped" MediaSessionCompat

Tags: android, android-mediasession

I am having a problem with the system UI on my android device crashes. This occurs every time that I try to activate the mediaSessionCompat. I have looked into following the advice of the following post:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/382
but is not worked. Below is just a simple code example with more information.

```
MediaSessionCompat mediaSessionCompat;
ComponentName mediaButtonReceiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MediaButtonReceiver.class);
mediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), "Tag", mediaButtonReceiver, null);

mediaSessionCompat.setCallback(mediaSessionCallback);
mediaSessionCompat.setFlags(
        MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
        MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS |
        MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_QUEUE_COMMANDS);

Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
mediaButtonIntent.setClass(this, MediaButtonReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
mediaSessionCompat.setMediaButtonReceiver(pendingIntent);
mediaSessionCompat.setRatingType(RatingCompat.RATING_NONE);
mediaSessionCompat.setShuffleMode(PlaybackStateCompat.SHUFFLE_MODE_NONE);
mediaSessionCompat.setQueue(mediaQueueManager.getMediaQueue());

MediaSessionCompat.Token token = mediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken();
setSessionToken(token);

mediaSessionCompat.setActive(true); // this is where the error occurs
```

I have tried to disable all the icons as well as setting them to a legacy icon  that I created via the Image Asset creator.

I am building the application with:

- minSdkVersion 21
- targetSdkVersion 27

Answer (score 0):

I found there error that was causing it. Surprisingly it was **NOT** anything to do with images, but instead had to do with setting of a bundle with extra information.

Below is code snippet where the error occured after I set the metadata:

```
    Bundle bundleExtras = new Bundle();
    bundleExtras.putSerializable(
            MediaSessionExtras.MEDIA_SHARED_IMAGE.name(),
            getMediaImage()
    );

    mediaSessionCompat.setExtras(bundleExtras);
```

FYI the `getMediaImage()` did not return any `null` values and all information inside the `serializable` object was initted to a value.

Hopefully if someone has the same weird error this helps!